# Get specific facebook page information using Koala gem

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, koala

I am trying to get the value of a facebook page using graph api.

The user will insert the link of the page into the input page, suppose

```
page_name = "https://www.facebook.com/FacebookDevelopers"

@graph_api.get_object(page_name)
```

but I got an error like

```
{"error"=>{"message"=>"Unknown path components: /www.facebook.com/FacebookDevelopers", "type"=>"OAuthException", "code"=>2500, "fbtrace_id"=>"GxQDg9JYZoU"}}
```

Comment: Can u elaborate what is value?

Comment: @HaseebAhmad, generally while using the graph api explorer, when u put `me` you will get all of your public data, so in my case I want to get the data of facebook public page like celebrity page, app page,etc .
I know that I can get it just like u said but I want to pass the url of the page as the name of the page is not always right

Answer (score 1):

In Koala I get posts of page like this

```
@graph = Koala::Facebook::API.new("secret_token");
statuses = @graph.get_connections(page_name, "feed", {"limit" => "25"});
```

E.g page_name = "humansofnewyork"

Comment: yes I know about that, but is it possible to use the url like this one
`https://www.facebook.com/FacebookDevelopers`

Comment: I don't think so there is any major difference between  them. Can you tell me why not only name?

Comment: because not all page name will be simple like "humansofnewyork". There are pages with obscure name like "Chronicler-1631319773789615" and koala do not understand these obscure names

Comment: The secret_token expires every 2 months. How can I do that without the need to update the secret token?